# PySide close window function receiving custom arguments

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I have main function from within I'm creating one instance of the Control class and one instance of the GuiWindow class. This GuiWindow object have methods that accepts the previous mentioned instance of the Control class as their arguments. But GuiWindow doesn't have Control object as its own attribute! It receives it as his own method's arguments when called from main function. So everything works, GuiWindow has event listeners and in accordance with them he calls Control and Control does whatever it needs to do... But Control needs to do something very important when user closes GUI window!

All my current closeEvent function does is the following:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):

    quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit',
            quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        event.accept()
        exit()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```

What if I want to pass object of Control class to this closeEvent function? Is that possible? I don't know how to overwrite the closeEvent function so that it knows that it needs to call some Control method. If I put Control class object as the closeEvent function arguments it doesn't work of course...

Has anyone any idea? Should I use some kind of Signal and Event mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my closeEvent function call method of my Control class by using Signal and Event mechanism. I created the following class:

```
class ExitApp(QtCore.QObject):
    exit_app_signal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

    def exit_app(self, exit_message):
        self.exit_app_signal.emit(exit_message)
```

which object I connected to the desired method of my Control class, and which I called in the following manner:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):

    quit_msg = "Are you sure you want to exit the program?"
    reply = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit',
            quit_msg, QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes, QtGui.QMessageBox.No)

    if reply == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
        self.exit_app.exit_app('Properly exit.')
        event.accept()
        exit()
    else:
        event.ignore()
```